# Two restricted areas in a row causing internal error

Tags: anylogic

i model a order picking system. To ensure that the conveyor dont get to full, i use a restricted area for some conveyors:

[image: two conveyers going into one]

At runtime i get an internal Error that says:

```
Internal error: Wurzel.area.conveyor4.hold received cancel notification for Wurzel.flow_controller.injected_orders[128] in unblocked state
```

This is where the error occurs:
[image: conveyor 4 internal error]

Is it a bad practise to model restricted areas directly after another?
And is there a wey to prevent that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i can't reproduce your problem, can you upload your model? I mean upload the minimal version that produces this error

Comment: Hey @Felipe, thank you for your response. Maybe this is because i use anylogic 8.1. I fixed it with a queue with capacity 1.